# PHP accepts IF statement although it's false

Tags: php

PHP considers this IF statement as true although the variable equals 0 NOT 'subjob'!

```
echo 'start';
$my_var = 0;
//Here, the result should skip the if BUT it doesn't: 
if($my_var == 'subjob'){
    echo $l_job_par_type;
}
echo 'end';
die();
```

The last result is:

```
start0end
```

Why is that?

Comment: `'subjob'`, cast to a number, is `0`. Which is obviously equal to `0`. Use `===` instead. (I actually had to deal with this "feature" in my own code today XD)

Comment: *"If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically."* - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. This is weird why this was the first time I have this issue!